# Python: Alternative for subprocess Popen for long time tasks

Tags: python, parallel-processing, subprocess

I already looked for similar questions but none of them were suitable for my usecase.
Here is a simple example of what I want to achieve, because the whole code is too long and not relevant:

```
While rc is None and process_list:
    rc = self.process.poll()
    output = self.process.stdout.readline()
    if some-condition:
        # doing stuff with output
    if other-condition:
        process = subprocess.Popen(some_cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
        fd = process.stdout.fileno()
        fl = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
        fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)
        process_list.append(process)
    check_process_list


def check_process_list(process_list):
    if process_list:
        for (i, (process)) in enumerate(process_list):
            if process.poll() is not None:
                output = process.stdout.readlines()
                # doing stuff with output
                process_list.pop(i)
```

The idea is that my main process spawn a subprocess (a C program), continously read its output (which can take several days), do stuff with the output and when some condition are met: spawn other process using subprocess.Popen.

This works, however it's not robust as subprocess.Popen put results in a 64K buffer and it may happens that this buffer will be filled, hanging the subprocess a keeping the program running indefinitely in the while loop.

The documentation explicitly says that subprocess Popen isn't suitable for long running tasks, however I can't find any alternative for this task.
All the subprocess that could have been written in Python were written in Python and I'm using multiprocessing module to spawn them.
But for two of these task I have no other solution than running C binaries.
Using communicate is no option for me as I need the subprocess to run in parallel, waiting for them to end is of no use.

If someone could suggest a more appropriate way to achieve that I would be grateful!

Comment: Can you have the processes write to a file? Then you can just poll the contents of the files instead.

Comment: Hey, sorry for my late reply. Yes I can do that, however I'll likely avoid this solution and find a proper way to do the same I did with subprocess.popen but with long running tasks. It is say it is not suitable for long running task so I wanted to know what are the alternatives (if there're ones?)
Thanks you anyway